# check whether a given property type is a typeof(list<>)

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, typeof

I have three lists something like `List<EmpRoles> , List<EmpVisibility> , List<EmpProps>.`

Now I want to perform certain operations on them. For this first I have to check whether the property is of type list or not.
I have use if block something like below

```
if ( propertyName == "EmpRoles" || propertyName == "EmpVis" || propertyName == "EmpProps")
```

Is there any better way of doing this thing , or is it possible to put some typeof(list<>) conditions. I know typeof(list<>) won't work here. Either i have to use typeof(list)...
Can Someone help in making a generic way to identify the list type properties?

Comment: It's not really clear why it is possible to do that with `propertyName`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem, what problem are you trying to solve that you came up with your current solution that you are asking about in this question.

Comment: I agree with @ScottChamberlain your approach is weird, you can definitely achieved that by checking generic param of List type but you should not try pass not related object to the same method and try to make that method some god-like object that can handle anything, create special method for each list and try to divide / branch the workflow for each list as soon as possible so you don't have to end up with some weird method that you can pass any type - c# is strong typed language with support of generics make use of that ;)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain i want to perform some operations only on list type property for that i have use if block with there name. I want to check the property type is list or not without using there name.

Comment: @tia with property name i can easily identify that it is a type of list.

Comment: It would be easier if you include some of your code in the question. It is not clear what is there in your code e.g. `PropertyInfo` or some `object` with unknown types or what.

Answer (score 3):

Checking that a type is a `List<T>` requires ensuring that:

- the type is generic by checking its [`IsGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictype) property,
- the generic type base is `System.List<>` by checking the result of [`GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition) against `typeof(List<>)`
- type `T` is the one you want by checking [`GetGenericArguments()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments)

If all three conditions are met, you have your type:

```
var pt = myProperty.PropertyType;
if (pt.IsGenericType &&
    pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) {
    var elementType = pt.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if (elementType == typeof(EmpRoles)) {
        ...
    } else if (elenentType == typeof(EmpVisibility)) {
        ...
    } else if ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please write these conditions in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get generic parameter from list as following

```
var list = new List<EmpRoles>
var argType = list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

Here in `argType` you will get `typeof(EmpRoles)`